# Remote Site Supports TLSv1.1 and Higher but Still throwing callout exception

Tags: apex, webservices, callout, tls

Salesforce disabled TLSv1.0 for sandboxes on June 25, 2016.

Problem : Receiving TLS support error suddenly eventhough remote site and browser supports TLSv1.1 and higher versions.

Before June 2016, our remote site is not supported by TLSv1.1 and higher versions. Then we requested our remote site to upgrade their TLS versions to support callout. They also upgraded and we are able to give the callout without any issues.

Now We don't know what happened suddenly it is throwing the same old error when giving callout to the remote site.

> System.CalloutException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version
>   is not enabled or not supported by the client

Then went to Qualys SSL Labs and checked the TLS of our remote site. It is still supporting TLSv1.1 and higher versions

[image]

Also checked browser support for TLS. And TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 is enabled in browser too.

So we don't know why it is suddenly occurring. It was working last week also.

Any help is appreciable thanks!!.

***Update***

After contacting salesforce support regarding the above problem, they are saying

> As discussed, the "Allow TLS 1.0 Past Soft Disablement in Sandbox
>   Orgs" for your Sandbox Org is being checked as true, which means that
>   your Sandbox Org is using TLS v1.0.
>
> I am still investigating the case regarding the permission "Allow TLS
>   1.0 Past Soft Disablement in Sandbox Orgs" with my team internally and my next update would be by the end of the day.

Comment: Another user had similar issue on their server despite the sites saying they supported tls1.1. May be similar here. Either way off topic on SFSE I believe and will require the IT investigation on the server's side: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/cannot-connect-to-https-tls1test-salesforce-com-services-soap-u-34-0/157651#157651

Comment: About the reopen vote: what answer are you actually expecting from the community ? That isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that your remote site still has TLS 1.0 enabled.

The whole reason why Salesforce is forcing everyone to start using TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 is for security reasons, and simply having TLS 1.0 as an option opens you up to what's called a "protocol-downgrade attack".

In this situation, it appears that your remote site (the 'server' in your error message) specifically chose to use TLS 1.0. By refusing the connection, Salesforce is attempting to protect you from yourself.

Disabling TLS 1.0 on your remote site should fix things.

Comment: thanks for your words. I've contacted salesforce support regarding this issue. They are saying that it is not the problem of remote site. But TLSv1.0 is enabled in the organization level. I'll post the message from support person below.

Comment: I've added the message in Question itself